# Object.assign() in IE11 with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I know that this issue has been discussed a billion times, but it seems that none of the solutions I can find here are helping in my case.

This is what my **polyfills.browser.ts** looks like right now:

```js
import 'ie-shim';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

As stated before, I tried different approaches for solving this.

I tried adding all imports that are uncommented by default:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

I tried using

```
import "core-js/client/shim";
```

and also

```
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.assign';
```

and

```
import 'core-js';
```

All of these were added to the top of polyfills.browser.ts

None seems to help and I keep getting **Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'** in IE11.

Comment: Can you give this a try  https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign?

Comment: I had a look at it before, but as I understood, I would need to actually use it whenever assign is needed, right? The call in question, however, is somewhere in one of the node modules used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.assign` is ES2015 and is covered by a polyfill:

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
```

Or for a broader range of ES2015 polyfills:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
```

The reason why it is preferable to list ES2015 polyfills in Angular application instead of importing `core-js/es6` is that `core-js/es6/promise` polyfill is already covered by Zone.js and may cause problems,.

If this doesn't work and

> Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

error occurs, this means that `polyfills` bundle wasn't loaded in browser, or a piece of code where `Object.assign` occurs was evaluated before `polyfills` bundle was loaded.

Comment: I just added a console.log() to the polyfills file, and I get an output in my app, which means that it is loaded. How can I find out if something is evaluated before the bundle is loaded?

Comment: Load it early in <head>. The way how the app is bundled depends on your setup. But of course, it's preferable for `polyfills` to be a separate bundle, because it should be loaded ASAP.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Had to make sure the order is correct in webpack :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even using polyfill on IE11, but not every time. The problem was that sometimes main script was being loaded before polyfills, so I've made the following change in webpack config:

```
       new CommonsChunkPlugin({
-        name: 'polyfills',
-        chunks: ['polyfills']
+        name: ['polyfills', 'main'].reverse(),
       })
```

So now with just:

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['polyfills', 'main'].reverse(),
})
```

it seems to work properly